# Using ELK Stack in Docker with docker-compose with x.pack auth failed to authenticate the user

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-x-pack

I want to use the elk stack with docker.

for this i created a docker-compose file. 
Everything works fine as long as I have X-Pack deactivated.

But now I want to have a login in the kibana UI and therefore i want to use the x-pack

I defined the UserName and Passsword in the environment of the elasticsearch and also logstash.

But i always get this exceptionm

> elasticsearch_1  | [2017-11-27T09:25:58,190][INFO
>   ][o.e.x.s.a.AuthenticationService] [clEpqom] Authentication of
>   [elastic] was terminated by realm [reserved] - failed to authenticate
>   user [elastic]

Any hints of what i'm doing wrong?
Here my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-platinum:6.0.0
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ELASTIC_USERNAME: "elastic"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: "MyPw123"
      http.cors.enabled: "true"
      http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.0.0
    environment:
      xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url: "172.17.0.1:9200"
      xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: "elastic"
      xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: "MyPw123"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.0.0
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge
```

**UPDATE**
Using the default password "changeme" does work.

Comment: Maybe a 'stupid' remark but what happens when you don't use compose but start the containers manual and wait some seconds every time. (First ES, than logstash, than kibana)? Maybe Kibana tries to connect while logstash isn't up already?

Comment: didn't tryed it one by one but i can see that even after some minutess, when everything is up and running the error occurs

Comment: Can you with the api if the password is changed + logs are arrived in logstash? 
`curl -u elastic 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v` (check indices on ES)

Comment: some posted a comment that is now deleted, but it was right. when i use the default pw "changeme" it works...

Comment: Ow yeah, I deleted it because I thought it was deprecated for 6.0.0 (I didn't use the newest version yet). It seems the password didn't change by setting it in the docker compose file

Comment: @ivthillo but it works. but i don't know now how to change it ? I expected the config  in the elastic search to do this. do i have to define others creds in the config file of elastic?

Comment: I earlier versions I used: 
`curl -u elastic -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/elastic/_password?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "password": "supersecret"
}
'`

Comment: But it could be it's different in 6.0.0: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-change-password.html (Post instead of Put, don't know if it matters actually)

Comment: ok thank you , the unexpected password was reason for this problem. i'll check it and maybe reopen another question if i find a problem. Can you post your comment as an answer so i can mark it as the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your elastic (admin) password in the cluster by using:

```
curl -u elastic -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/elastic/_password?prett‌​y' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' 
{ 
    "password": "supersecret" 
}
```

The default password is `changme`.

If you really want to set your configuration in docker-compose I would recommend to look at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_configuring_logstash_for_docker.html#_configuring_logstash_for_docker) page. I think you can not set your elasticsearch password as environment variable for logstash (they are not in the env var list). You have to change it in config files or build your own image. (Same for Kibana I'm afraid).